# Clearing node stream internal buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, serial-port

I am using Node Serialport to set an event listener and I am then checking to see if the data that is being streamed over the connection has the correct units. If these units do not match the user's set units, I am using the `.pause()` method and notifying the user that the device is not transmitting the correct units. The user can then press a "Resume" button which calls the `.resume()` method.

According to the Node docs: "The readable.pause() method will cause a stream in flowing mode to stop emitting 'data' events, switching out of flowing mode. Any data that becomes available will remain in the internal buffer."

The problem seems to be that I need to clear this internal buffer. As it currently is, I need to call `.resume()` many times to go through all the buffered data which has the wrong units.

Here is a general idea of how the code is set up:

```
//Listen for data events and pipe them through a parser.
path.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' })).on('data', data => {
  //do something with data
})

//Then if data units !== set units, call path.pause()
// User can press "Resume" once the device's units are changed.
<button onClick={() => path.flush(() => path.resume())}>Resume</button>
```

How can I clear the internal buffer or is there an alternative to `.pause()` that avoids this problem entirely without closing and then re-opening the connection?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you just want to unpipe the source:

```
 source.unpipe(target);
```

that way, all the data is streaming into nowhere, then  to resume somewhen just

```
source.pipe(target);
```

again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave this a shot but I got the same issue of needing to call `source.pipe(target)` several times.
According to the Node docs:

"Calling readable.pause(), readable.unpipe(), or receiving backpressure will cause the readable.readableFlowing to be set as false, temporarily halting the flowing of events but **not halting the generation of data**."

So I still end up with an internal buffer full of data with the wrong units and then when I call `source.pipe(target)` the data triggers the check I have to see if the units are correct.